# A-Frame, AR.JS. How to position object within the NFT-Marker?

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, ar.js

I have a problem with positioning video element right within the NFT marker area.
Digged through AR.JS and AFRAME documentation with no luck.

**The problem:** on each device with different screen resolution and camera resolution video is positioned different.
If i set sourceWidth, sourceHeight, displayWidth, displayHeight according to my PC webcam i no longer able to see the object on my smartphone, because it gets rendered off-screen.

The second problem is to make video element exactly sized like the marker. On different devices and cameras video size is different.

[See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oX3i.jpg)

My Code is almost similar to nft examples in ar.js repository.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@c5eabc1ac708a76a0dbe9538c40ecd290af65714/dist/aframe-master.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        AFRAME.registerComponent('videohandler', {
            init: function () {
                var marker = this.el;

                this.vid = document.querySelector("#vid");

                marker.addEventListener('markerFound', function () {
                    this.vid.play();
                }.bind(this));
    
        marker.addEventListener('markerLost', function() {
            this.vid.pause();
            this.vid.currentTime = 0;
        }.bind(this));
            }
        });
    };
</script>

<body style="margin: 0px; overflow: hidden">

    <a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;" renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: false; " embedded arjs="trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false; sourceWidth:414; sourceHeight:736; displayWidth: 414; displayHeight: 736;">
      <a-assets>
        <video src="https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" preload="auto" id="vid" response-type="arraybuffer" loop
          crossorigin webkit-playsinline autoplay muted playsinline preload="true"></video>
      </a-assets>

      <a-nft type="nft" videohandler url="https://arjs-cors-proxy.herokuapp.com/https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/data/dataNFT/pinball" smooth="true" smoothCount="10" smoothTolerance="0.01" smoothThreshold="5" preload="true">
        <a-video src="#vid" position="0 0 0" width="300" height="424" rotation="-90 0 0" videoelement>
        </a-video>
      </a-nft>

      <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
</body>
```

Live example in repo: https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js/aframe/examples/image-tracking/nft-video/
Scan this image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/examples/image-tracking/nft-video/pinball.jpg

Is there a way, for example, to get marker size and position and set video element exact size and position?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I also recently encountered this issue and you can view this issue on [github](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/issues/4) but this issue is open.

So after searching for days  I have found [this](https://github.com/hiukim/mind-ar-js)  amazing Github repo which seems wrapper to AR js solved this problem of centering the 3d objects/videos on the detected image.

- Mind AR Github repo : https://github.com/hiukim/mind-ar-js
- Mind AR docs : https://hiukim.github.io/mind-ar-js-doc/

Using Mind AR

1. Boilerplate code  https://hiukim.github.io/mind-ar-js-doc/quick-start/overview
2. Compile Target image (create mind files) https://hiukim.github.io/mind-ar-js-doc/tools/compile/

Comment: Looks promising, I'll have a look on it!

Comment: would love to see your work @alpha-helix

Comment: I have a problem with mind AR, when I open it on my smartphone, the position of the object doesn't match, if I access it using the webcam on my computer's browser, it's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this issue using NFT and discovered that the x,y,z position axis don't really adjust (or are out of whack) until you modify more than one axis at a time.

Not sure if it helps, but that worked for me because changing one axis at a time and checking the position was a headache.  Also, make your adjustments drastic +/- 300 so you know which angle it adjusts because I'm pretty sure my axis were screwed up. Im not sure if orientation wanted me to have the tracked object on a surface vs. in my hand - but it made it difficult to test.

Additionally using an iphone in Safari worked well but an android on chrome was having tracking and positional issues.

I used the iphone on Safari to set the tracking and position then verified it with a different device.